# cannot connect to mongo cluster - user is not allowed to do action [getLog] on [admin.]

Tags: mongodb, deployment

I have created a user and added my IP to whitelist.

when trying to connect to a cluster through mongo shell, i am required to enter the following line: mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster0.****.mongodb.net/" --username --password

I have filled in credentials for username and password and replaced dbname with my database name(tried using non-existing one as well in case that was the problem). it connects to the shell, but then crashes with the following error:

> Error while trying to show server startup warnings: user is not allowed to do action [getLog] on [admin.]
> MongoDB Enterprise atlas-7cwf8s-shard-0:PRIMARY>

tried googling and youtubing the issue, but cannot find the match on how to fix it.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

That message says that the shell is unable to show you server startup warnings. It's expected in Atlas environment.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that's your own cluster, then:

1. Check the user in [Atlas](https://cloud.mongodb.com) > **Database Access**
2. Check the **MongoDB Roles** header in the table.

If it's not atlas Admin, you can't issue this command:

```
db.adminCommand({getLog:"startupWarnings"})
```

Or any admin command, which is issued or tested automatically in the connection, hence the error.

3. Edit MongoDB Roles to the highest privileges (atlas Admin)

But you can still work anyways.

---

- If you're accessing someone else's cluster, then there isn't much to do.